# Would it be possible to lasso an emu-like bird without harming it?

Tags: creature-design, fauna

Think Moa, very big bird, kept as livestock in a western-ish world. Could they be safely lassoed? Their necks are quite long and, I imagine, delicate, at least when compared to cattle or horses. If their necks would break under a rope, could a lasso instead wrap around their bodies somehow?

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it. That being said, what research on corralling emus have you done already? What did you not find useful or clear about what you learned? The Worldbuilding community generally recommends research be conducted before asking a question. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour]. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Check this out ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPb4gLXYKgk - first hit on google for lasso emu

Comment: How is this off-topic? Exactly what other Stack is a valid landing place for a question about emu lasso-ing?

Comment: @kingledion Maybe [Pets SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/)? Just because there isn't another exchange dedicated to it doesn't mean it is appropriate for WB. I didn't vote to close, but I suspect the close-votes may be related to the searchability of the very real emu.

Comment: @Frostfyre I dare you ask "Is it safe to lasso my pet emu?" on Pets.SE.

Comment: The last time humans took on emus *we lost* !  Check out [The Emu War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu_War) and also this [video on the YouTube channel Today I Found Out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gDjQ3KAi1w).  So don;t worry about hurting them, worry about them hurting us. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safely is perhaps not the right word for it, but I would guess that it might work if the lasso fell to the bottom part of the neck, where it is thicker. I doubt that their neck would break, but they would perhaps choke on it.

However, maybe you would consider using one of these instead? They were actually used to hunt big birds, like the Moa (text from Wikipedia):

[image]

A bolas (plural: bolas or bolases; from Spanish bola, "ball", also known as boleadoras) is a type of throwing weapon made of weights on the ends of interconnected cords, used to capture animals by entangling their legs. Bolas were most famously used by the gauchos (South American cowboys), but have been found in excavations of Pre-Columbian settlements, especially in Patagonia, where indigenous peoples (particularly the Tehuelche) used them to catch 200-pound guanaco (llama-like mammals) and ñandú (birds). The Mapuche and the Inca army used them in battle. Researchers have also found bolas in North America at the Calico Early Man Site.

[image]

Comment: I am not at all sure if this wouldn't violate the "not harming them" condition the op mentions - as I recall, bolas didn't *only* tangle the legs, the weighted ends were heavy and the momentum from the rope swinging them around the target could break bones.  It does say it was used to capture, but I don't know the tolerances for "harmed" - they might tolerate a lot more harm if they used the bola to hunt rather than, as the OP mentions, to herd domesticated birds.

Comment: Agreed! I have no previous experience with the use of Bolas, so I am purely relying on the info I gathered above.